# Http Route called multiple times

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose, cloud9-ide, everyauth

When the following route is called in express, it is actually executed 6 times. The console.log is printed 6 times, and my mongoose logic is executed 6 times (saves 6 time in database).

I then get returned a http 500 from cloud9ide "Could not proxy request". I am really confused, I have no loops in my code, how can this happen? The console.log("in else (2)"); get printed 6 times.

Edit: I have tried the mongooseLogic code with various parts commented out, and the issue was still there. This looks like it isn't a mongoose issue.

Second edit: I have changed the post for get and hardcoded the body that would be sent, and the route was executed only once.

Third edit: I am also using everyauth for session/authentication with the facebook oauth.

```
app.post("/result/:userId/:elementId", function(req, res) {
  var receivedJSON = req.body;    

  console.log("In route");

  //Making sure the receive request is valid
  if(typeof(receivedJSON.type) !== undefined) {
    mongooseLogic.saveResults(req.params.elementId, receivedJSON, req.params.userId, function(message) {
      if(message === "Success") {
        res.json({ success: true,  message: 'Result saved.'});    
      }
      else {
        res.json({ success: false,  message: 'Error in saving results. Trace: ' + message});
      }
    });
  }
  else {
    res.json({ success: false,  message: 'Failed, Invalid object sent to server'});   
  }
});
```

Code on the mongooseLogic file:

```
var saveResults = function(elementRefId, receivedResult, userId, callback){

    if(elementRefId.toString().length !== 24 ){
       callback("Invalid objectId for elementId");
    }
    else{
            Result.findOne({ "id" : userId, "serieResult.id": elementRefId }, function(err, result){
                if(err){
                    callback("No Document found: " + err);
                }
                else if( result === null){
                    console.log("in null");
                    var tempResult =  {
                        id           : elementRefId, 
                        unit         : receivedResult.unit, 
                        value        : receivedResult.value 
                    }
                    Result.update({ "id" : userId}, { $push: {"serieResult": tempResult}}, {upsert: true}, function(err){
                        if(err){
                            callback("Error in saving result (Distance): " + err);
                        }
                        else{
                            callback("Success");
                        }
                    });
                }
                else{            
                    Result.update({ "id" : userId, "serieResult.id": elementRefId },
                        { $set:{
                            "serieResult.$.unit"        : receivedResult.unit,
                            "serieResult.$.value"       : receivedResult.value,
                        },{upsert: true}, function(err){
                            if(err){
                                callback("Cant update doc: " + err);
                            }
                            else{
                                console.log("in else (2)");
                                 callback("Success");
                            }
                    }); 
                }
            }); 
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: How is your client code calling this? Can you reproduce this with cURL?

Comment: It is a ajax (jquery get json) it is only called once, because I have inspected the query in the google chrome developper tools.

Comment: Can you e-mail your username / project name to support@c9.io, so we can help you debug this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was a problem with the Cloud9 proxy that interfered. The problem was adressed thanks to this issue and has been resolved.

Comment: Thanks to yourself and cloud9ide for the turn around.